# How to filter ComboBox item according by TextBox1 (VB.NET)?

Tags: vb.net, combobox, connection

I want when the TextBox1 was input, the combobox1 filtered according the TextBox1. 
How I can do it?
This is my code:

```
    >>>The TextBox1 entered like this:
Textbox1.text = 2015-02       


    >>>This is load the ComboBox
    cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select * from TABLE where COL1 = TextBox1.Text", Conn)
    rd = cmd.ExecuteReader
    Do While rd.Read
        COMBOBOX1.Items.Add(rd.Item(0))
    Loop

    >>>It work when I write like this:
    cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select * from TABLE where COL1 = '2015-02'", Conn)
    rd = cmd.ExecuteReader
    Do While rd.Read
        COMBOBOX1.Items.Add(rd.Item(0))
    Loop


   >>>  But i wanna the COL1 according by TextBox1.Text
```

Answer (score 0):

change your command line to

```
cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select * from TABLE where COL1 = "' & TextBox1.Text & "'", Conn)
```

it will work.As of your code,the command will check for "textbox.text" in COL1

**AS per Comments recived,using parameterized query you command line will look like**

```
cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select * from TABLE where COL1 = @text", Conn)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text",TextBox1.Text)
```

Comment: This code is susceptible to `SQL` injection attacks, you should use `Parameterized Queries` to help prevent this.